# using IRequiresSessionState, IReadOnlySessionState breaks oauth2 but is required to set cookie

Tags: c#, session, cookies, oauth-2.0

I have a generic handler written in C# - this is called as part of an OAuth2 process to validate users via Google.

Once the correct user is identified I need to set a cookie so the rest of the site can then identify the user.

The trouble is in order to set session variables the handler needs to implement IRequiresSessionState - when I do that - then the OAuth 2 process fails with the following error.

**Unexpected OAuth authorization response received with callback and client state that does not match an expected value**

So I can implement OAuth or write a session variable but cannot do both. I could get OAuth to call the first page but then the code can be seen in the URL (which I would rather not do - as it gives clues for any nefarious person to break security ). I could get a page to call the handler, return JSON to identify the user and have the page itself set the session variable, then go to the first page - but this page would have no content, as well as requiring two hops - so how can you have an HTML page which is essentially empty, or set the session without IRequiresSessionState breaking the session.

The code for the OAuth handler is shown below.

```
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        NetworkParameters networkParameters     = null;
        NetworkParameter networkParameter       = null;
        WebServerClient consumer                = null;
        AuthorizationServerDescription server   = null;
        IAuthorizationState grantedAccess       = null;
        LoginResult loginResult                 = null;

        String code                             = String.Empty;

        String result                           = String.Empty;
        String consumerSecret                   = String.Empty;
        String consumerKey                      = String.Empty;
        String securityCookieVal                = String.Empty;
        Uri tokenEndpoint                       = null;
        Uri authorizationEndpoint               = null;

        Profile profile                         = null;
        Profile profile2                        = null;
        Profiles profiles                       = null;
        NetworkAuthorizations authorizations    = null;
        NetworkAuthorization na                 = null;

        try
        {
            loginResult             = new LoginResult();
            tokenEndpoint           = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
            authorizationEndpoint   = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=auto");

            // retrieve network parameters
            networkParameters       = new NetworkParameters(Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnection);
            authorizations          = new NetworkAuthorizations(Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnection);

            networkParameter        = networkParameters.Select("GOOGLE");
            code                    = context.Request["code"];
            consumerKey             = networkParameter.ClientId;
            consumerSecret          = networkParameter.ClientSecret;

            // set up request
            server                          = new AuthorizationServerDescription();
            server.AuthorizationEndpoint    = authorizationEndpoint;
            server.TokenEndpoint            = tokenEndpoint;
            server.ProtocolVersion          = ProtocolVersion.V20;

            // initialise webserver client
            consumer = new WebServerClient(server, consumerKey, consumerSecret);
            consumer.ClientCredentialApplicator = ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter(consumerSecret);

            // retrieve access
            grantedAccess = consumer.ProcessUserAuthorization();

            profile  = GoogleServices.GetProfile(grantedAccess.AccessToken);
            profiles = new Profiles(Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnection);
            profile2 = profiles.SelectByNetworkId(profile.Network, profile.NetworkId);

            if (profile2 == null)
            {
                na = new NetworkAuthorization()
                {
                    Id              = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    AccessToken     = grantedAccess.AccessToken,
                    ExpirationDate  = (DateTime)grantedAccess.AccessTokenExpirationUtc,
                    IssueDate       = (DateTime)grantedAccess.AccessTokenIssueDateUtc,
                    RefreshToken    = grantedAccess.RefreshToken,
                    Network         = profile.Network,
                    NetworkId       = profile.NetworkId
                };

                authorizations.Insert(na); 
                profiles.Insert(profile);
            }

            loginResult.UserId = profile.NetworkId;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {

            loginResult.Status.Status   = "ERROR";
            loginResult.Status.Message  = e.Message;

        }
        finally
        { 
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginResult));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer - but I got around this by passing a randomly generated id to the first page of the website, and storing it against the user - cookie was set when the first page was called.

Not really secure sending such information in the query string but will suffice in what is a prototype - eventual plan is to use Node.js where this will not be an issue.